# How to specify the Python version I want to install lxml in?

Tags: python, linux, lxml

I am new to Linux. On my Oracle Virtual Machine, I have several versions of Python installed.

Now I would like to install the `lxml` library in my Python 3.7, but I don't know how to specify the terminal to do so. The command  `pip install lxml`  that was recommanded to me returns : `Requirement already satisfied : lxml in <my path to Python 3.8>`

What I understand is that by default, it installs `lxml` in Python 3.8. How can I change that into Python 3.7 please ?

Comment: There are multiple solutions and it depends on how exactly you ended up with multiple versions. The absolutely simplest way forward is to use a virtual environment. `/path/to/python3.7 -m venv virtualenv` creates a new virtual environment in `virtualenv` which you can then `activate`: `. ./virtialenv/bin/activate` (notice the lone dot before the space!). Now when you run `pip` it will be the one which belongs to the virtual environment, and it will install things into the virtual environment, not system-wide.

Comment: The easiest way to handle multiple python versions is definitely virtualenvs (you can look around pyenv or conda which is a bit more than just a venv).

Or you can do something like: `python3.7 -m pip install yourpackage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How can I change that into Python 3.7 please ?*

According to [python docs regarding working with multiple versions of python installed in parallel](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) you might

> On Linux, Mac OS X, and other POSIX systems, use the versioned Python
> commands in combination with the `-m` switch to run the appropriate copy
> of `pip`

so in your case

```
python3.7 -m pip install lxml
```

Answer (score 0):

You must know how to start the Python3.7 version. If you start it with `full_path_to_python37`, then you should use the following to install `lxml` in it:

```
full_path_to_python37 -m pip install lxml
```